# Can't relocate with TortoiseSVN 1.14

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

The problem is with TortoiseSVN Version 1.14.

When I try to relocate a solution it never succeed:

[image: Relocating...]

Is there a way to make it manually ?

Comment: Please double-check that the new URL is correct and actually points to a Subversion repository (and not something else such as a regular web page). You may also try the "Clean up" command just in case.

Comment: I think that it’s worth trying to run “svn relocate” from command prompt. Any errors?

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [`svn relocate`](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.relocate.html) command. Show the errors if it does not succeed.

Answer (score 0):

As banrep said, svn relocate
By doing this, it should work without problems as long as the svn version is greater than 1.7.

svn relocate http://old-dominio.com/svn/proyect http://new-dominio.com.mx/svn/proyect

If the client tool is not installed, you must open the installer again (without uninstalling TortoiseSVN) and include it, as in the following image:

[image: you]

After installed, the svn command will be available in cmd.